# Left angle bracket on white when opening my website

Tags: performance, loading, angle

I have a strange problem.
When I enter my site http://www.dinomuhic.com I sometimes see a left angle bracket in the top left corner on white background for a short time (1-2 sec) before my page is displayed.

I don't know why this is happening. I thought its because I send an AJAX request at document.ready state but I removed it and placed the stuff, which the AJAX would load at first entering, directly into the DOM so it doesnt have to be loaded and go through all the AJAX code but it still pops up.

It looks really unprofessional and if it has to do something with laoding speed of the page I would rather use a preloader instead of this happening. Perhaps some of you know why its happening.

Thank you

PS: and PLEASE for the love of god, don't tell me to get rid of jQuery/UI or the like buttons. There are millions of other pages which use these and they don't have such problems. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuz it's in your code before your meta redirect. Here's your culprit:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.dinomuhic.com/2010/index.php"><
<title>DINOMUHIC.COM - The official Homepage of Dino Muhic</title>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Notice the index.php">**<**

Comment: Thank you but I can't find it. Its nowhere in my code. the <meta> tag up there isnt either.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you and was searching in the redirected page. Found it now.